# UIImageView not showing image in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

The `UIImageView` is not showing the image up in my custom `UITableViewCell`.

Can't figure out why, I have tried both methods of setting the `Image` property it in the `Interface Builder` and then tried setting up an `IBOutlet` and setting the `.image` property.

None seem to work. Why is this happening to me?!?!

**Class with TableViewDataSource**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LatestMessageCell") as LatestMessageCell

    cell.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Logo")

    return cell
}
```

**Custom Cell Class**

```
class LatestMessageCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var cardBackgroundView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    cardBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    cardBackgroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cardBackgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    cardBackgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    cardBackgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: I'd say:
• Check that the outlet is set correctly
• Check that the image is loaded (maybe wrong image name?)

Answer (score 0):

Pls modify your Method and check:

```
let simpleTableIdentifier = "TableViewCell";

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

      var cell:LatestMessageCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier) as? LatestMessageCell

      if (cell == nil)
      {
           let nib:Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LatestMessageCell", owner: self, options: nil)
           cell = nib[0] as? LatestMessageCell
      }

      cell!.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Logo")

      return cell!
}
```